# Safari single side border radius not rendered correctly

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I'm trying to create a half circle border around a div using border-bottom to create this effect:
[image]

It renders correctly on chrome and firefox (can't test android although it appears correct in chrome dev tools) but on safari 11.0.3 and ios 11.2.6 you can see a top border appearing.

html:

```
<div class="circle-border-wrapper">
    <div class="circle-border">
        <h3>{{ .heading }}</h3>
        <p>{{ .text }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.circle-border-wrapper .circle-border:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -66px;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #ea3dd3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 187%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: consider box-shadow instead

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135196/css-1px-border-stroke-breaks-around-border-radius7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312429/safari-rendering-rounded-corners-incorrectly?rq=1

Comment: Box shadow doesn't give the tappered effect nor the visual appearance I'm looking for. Those linked posts I tried out but to no avail. Also, I'm not sure how relevant those older posts are for current safari version.

Comment: try filter drop-shadow

Comment: those post are old but they can be good one to find some tricks, as you may find recents answers/comment also related links

Comment: I tried drop shadow, but it doesn't render a crisp edge. Any other ideas?

Comment: After I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17210864/1880836) that explained what the issue is with safari, I was able to find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415694/1880836) that provided the solution.